# jQuery - count words in TEXTAREA

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I have a Javascript function that returns the number of words that I write into a textarea, but for some reasons, I wanted to write it using Jquery. And, although I tried, I didn't managed to get it, so that's why I'm here, I would be very, very grateful if you could help me.

This is the Javascript:

```
function contar() {
palabras = 1;
if (document.data.texto.value.length === '') palabras = 0;
for (count = 0; count < document.data.texto.value.length; count++) {
    if (document.data.texto.value.substring(count, count + 1) == ' ') palabras++;
}
document.data.cuenta.value = palabras;}
```

And this is the jQuery I've made:

```
(function () {
    var palabras = 1;
    if ($("[name=data] textarea[name=texto]").val().length === "") {
        palabras = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < $("[name=data] textarea[name=texto]").val().length; i++) {
        if ($("[name=data] textarea[name=texto]").val().substring(i, i + 1) == ' ')) {
            palabras++;
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, this is the HTML I use to display it:

```
<form name="data">
    <textarea name="texto" cols="40" rows="4" onkeyup="contar()" onkeypress="contar()"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="Text" name="cuenta" size="3" maxlength="3">
</form>
```

Comment: `.length` is an interger, not a string, so `.length === ""` will not work.

Comment: That doesn't really count the words now, does it ?

Comment: has it count spaces only or need to omit multispaces?

Comment: About this line : `if (document.data.texto.value.length === '')` How a length could be equals to an empty string ? And you should access you nodes with `document.getElementById` function, way more practical;

Comment: [Duplicate] mark is pointless. Major problem was to count **words** not **characters**. This problem has no solution in suggested duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working solution :

```
function contar(){
        alert($.trim($('[name="texto"]').val()).split(' ').filter(function(v){return v!==''}).length);
}
```

The `filter(function(v){return v!==''})` part removes empty strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhaYH/

Comment: I've managed to make it work (I needed a window load event and to change all the "$" as the host converted them to &#36;,  but that's all). Moreover, I've removed the .on event as the .click is the only event used, so I thought it wouldn't be necessary. 

Anyway, you've saved my life, thanks for that :P

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that cross my mind follows:

```
//function
function countWords(tx){
  return tx?tx.replace(/ +/g," ").replace(/\w+| $|^ /g,"").length+1:0;
}
//jQuery plugin
$.fn.countWords = function(){
 return countWords(this.val()) ;
};
```

Example
HTML:

```
<textarea id="tester"></textarea>
<p>WordsCount:<span id="counter">0</span></p>
```

JS:

```
$tester = $("#tester");
$tester.keyup(function(e){
  $("#counter").text($tester.countWords());
});
```

http://jsbin.com/EfukoYIs/3/edit?html,js,output

**Edit**
Finally I changed concept to count only words in proper meaning (no special chars etc.). The code follows:

```
//function
function countWords(tx){
  return tx.replace(/\w+/g,"x").replace(/[^x]+/g,"").length;
}
```

IMO it's much better.
http://jsbin.com/EfukoYIs/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes, it works in the jsbin, but when I try to use it in the web page, I can't manage to use it properly (maybe it's host's fault, because I don't really know what version of jQuery they have, but I'm completely sure that they don't even have 1.9.1 :/)

If you want to know, I've added the Jquery part between two script tags after the srcipt of the jquery, but it don't even works in jsbin >.<

Yes, I know I'm very noob  at this...

Comment: Maybe visibility scope is your problem. It's hard to say from my position. I assumed that major problem is to convert you function logic to be used in jQuery manner. 
For your HTML code just simple code should work: `alert($('[name="texto"]').countWords());`

Answer (score -2):

Get the value of the textarea, and split it on the space character which will give you an array.  Then return the length of that array.

**Updated** for empty string http://jsfiddle.net/ghyDs/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contar() {
        var value = $.trim($('[name="texto"]').val()),
            count = value == '' ? 0 : value.split(' ').length;

        $('[name="cuenta"]').val(count);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: And it makes even less sense than before.

Comment: @adeneo check the fiddle and maybe that will shed some light

Comment: It returns me 1 when textbox is empty. And it counts a word when there is 2 following spaces. And you forgot to name your function or to store it into a variable.

Comment: Still counts a word when there is 2 following spaces

Comment: @OlivierH, OP wanted a conversion this does exactly what the original function does.

Comment: Then you should make you script crashing :) I don't see how OP's code can be working.