# How to count words in a textarea by jquery and return that value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

```
function count(){  
  var val   = $.trim($('textarea').val()),  
      words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length,
      chars = val.length;
  if(!chars)words=0;

 return words;
}
```

This function always return 0? 
Please help.

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132933/jquery-count-words-in-textarea

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, I think following answer is more helpful.

Comment: Your word count [works just fine as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy8ja/). Why do you think there's an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the textarea value on spaces and then get the words length in it.
Try this:

```
var words = $('textarea').val().split(' ');
alert(words.length);//or return words.length;
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKUbr/1/)**

Comment: Why is this an improvement? "Try this" explains nothing.

Comment: @Dexpras is already splitting on spaces, however his version is better than yours because it trims and gets rid of adjacent spaces

Comment: @Dexpras: How did this answer your question? It's a less accurate version of what you're already doing.

Comment: @cookiemonster The different is this return words.length instead of return words. Thats what just I needed to know.

Comment: @Dexpras: In your version, `words` *is* the `length`. No difference. He's just storing the words in the `words` variable and returning `words.length`, while you're storing the `.length` of the words in the `words` variable and returning it.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, But the thing is it did not work that way.

Comment: @Dexpras: Yes, it does work. I copied your exact code into a demo, and posted it in a comment below your question. This answer is a worse version of your original code. I have no idea why people upvoted it.

Comment: This will not work accurate for many cases like leading spaces, trailing spaces, more than one space between two words.

Answer (score 0):

```
text_area = $('textarea').val();
text_area.length == 0 ? 0 : text_area.trim().split(/\s+\b/).length
```

Comment: Thanks, But I think looping is not necessary.