# For every textarea i create, i want it to have its 'personal word count' on it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below is to appear additional 2 textbox and 1 textarea everytime i click a button.

```
var x=1;
        var count=0;

        $('body').on('click','#add',function()
        {
            if(count < 6)
            {   
                $('#div').append("<div class='line'><input type='text' name = 'txta"+x+ "' id='txta"+ x +"'><span class =wordtab></span>      <textarea rows='9' onkeyup='countChar2(this)' cols='50' name = 'txtc"+x+ "' id='txtc"+ x +"'></textarea>   <span class =wordtab></span><input style = 'width:50px' type='text' name = 'txtb"+x+"' id='txtb"+ x +"'><span class =wordtab></span><button class='delete' value ='Delete Row'>Delete Row</button></div><div style='margin-left: 750px' id='charNum" + x + "'></div>");
                count++;
                x++;
            }
            else
            alert("Maximum 6 Skills");
        });

        $('body').on('click','.delete',function()
        {
        $(this).closest('.line').remove(); 

        count--;
        });
```

The below function is the code that i currently have (which i know its wrong) to put in a counter for every textarea that i added in.

```
        function countChar2(val) 
        {
             var len = val.value.length;
             if (len >= 200) 
             {
             val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);

            } 
            else 
            {
                var id = "charNum" + x;
                $(id).text((200 - len)+" words left");
            }
        };
```

So my goal is that everytime i click on the add row and start typing on the textarea, it will show the word count for that particular texarea just right below the textarea box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133617/how-to-count-words-in-a-textarea-by-jquery-and-return-that-value?rq=1

Comment: Why doesnt your code work though? What is the problem?

Comment: @RC. my word count works but idk how to append it so that it have an individual ID for every <div>

Comment: @DavidH. The problem is that the ID has to be unique for the word count but i do not know how to make it unique. I tried using my x variable but dont really know how to apply it

Answer (score 0):

To get a unique counter added to each textarea, you could append another div to the textarea with a specific class e.g.

Set the HTML structure to something such as:

```
<textarea></textarea><div class='text-count-area'>Word Count: 0</div>
```

Add the following JS at the point where each textarea is added e.g. just before 'count++' in your original code (note: this is not the most efficient way of doing this, but this will work easily with your current code):

```
 // Bind the text area to the keyup event
 $("textarea").on('keyup', function(val) {

    // Simple word count
    var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;

    // Write the word count to the immediate text-count-area div afterwards
    $(this).next(".text-count-area").text("Text count" + words);
 });
```

The word count is kept simple here for readability, but the logic from other answers (highlighted in the comments) could be implemented at this stage.

A JS Fiddle demo of this working is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ycrbook6/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Let see your example:

1. You add each div by `.append` method, it's correct
2. You count input symbols by `onkeyup` event, it's correct too
3. All you need is update your `countChar2` function because this function  has wrong body in that lines:

   ```
           var id = "charNum" + x;
           $(id).text((200 - len)+" words left");
   ```

First of all: try to debug your code via developer tools in your favorite browser with breaks in that lines. This step can give your much more and quickly info than posting question in stackoverflow :)

For `onkeyup` event you should use link to `this` object instead of `id` inside your function:

```
            $(val).parent().find('.words-left').val((200 - len));
```

This line uses `val` as a link to textarea object in just appended line. `.parent()` gives you access to wrapper and `find()` finds input for words left field. (I've added '.words-left' class to your input, see my fiddler bellow). And this code works in stage of your just added line.

Your code of `$('body').click()` should be executed, when document is fully loaded and DOM ready. But all your ids that you will create in future doesn't appends that DOM. That's why your delete function works properly - that function uses `class selector` instead of `id`.

Proposed by me code doesn't uses `id` selector because it is not needed. All that needs to me - link to current object in new line, `val` - what I need for that operation.

BTW: When you implement function that works with objects, such as `onkeyup='countChar2(this)'`, better way to use `object` as passed variable - `var countChar = function(obj) {`. Because `val` is using for scalar values  in common way.

You can check my code here https://jsfiddle.net/jo0cd3yr/1/